# Meteor Template.myTemplate.helpers not rendering output

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-helper

I am new to meteor and i am wondering why is it myTemplate.helper is not rendering its supposed output when i started putting these files in my /client/template directory. These are the following files:

/clinent/template/body.html:

```
<body>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            <div class="list-group">
            {{#each projects}}
                {{> projectList}}
            {{/each}}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

/client/template/body.js:

```
Project = new Mongo.Collection("project");

if (Meteor.isClient) {

Template.body.helpers({
    projects: function(){
        var projects = Project.find({});

        return projects;
    }
});

};
```

/client/template/templates.html:

```
<template name="projectList">
<a href="#" id="{{id}}" class="list-group-item {{#if active}} active {{/if}}">
    {{name}}
    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash pull-right del"></i>
</a>
</template>
```

However it is rendering the ouptut properly when i put body.html and body.js at the root `/` directory.

Comment: This is really weird, I can't reproduce the issue. Code seems correct :/

Comment: Hmm is it probably because there are part of the code that is preventing it from rendering the list? Because there actually more codes to it, i just showed that specific part because thats where im having issue

Comment: I think I figured it out just a moment after posting my comment :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I know what the problem is.

```
Project = new Mongo.Collection("project");
```

Should be available to both client and server, when you move body.js to client folder it is automatically [served only to client](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/structuringyourapp), and it breaks the app.

Try following structure:

/client/template/body.js:

```
Template.body.helpers({
    projects: function(){
        var projects = Project.find({});

        return projects;
    }
});
```

/collections.js

```
Project = new Mongo.Collection("project");
```

Note that you don't need if(Meteor.isClient) when creating files inside client folder.

Comment: Does it mean i should put the db declaration in the /server directory then subscribe on the client side? Is that your suggestion?

Comment: I edited the answer, for now (if you have autopublish added to your project) you can just make sure that Project collection is available to both client and server.

Comment: Ok let me try this one. Thanks sir!

Answer (score 0):

I think it will work if you use

```
Template.projectList.helpers
```

instead of

```
Template.body.helpers
```

When the helper is for a template then you have to put the template name and not body.